# How could i save listbox items even if i restart the app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, wp7test

How could i save listbox items even if i restart the app in the windows phone app. I want them to be sort of saved somehow, in a file, and then read them on the next start of the app. Please help..
Ok i am updating with a code:

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        #region VariableDeclaration

```
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    WebBrowserTask Facebook = new WebBrowserTask();
    WebBrowserTask YouTube = new WebBrowserTask();
    WebBrowserTask Odnoklassniki = new WebBrowserTask();
    WebBrowserTask Vkontakte = new WebBrowserTask();
    List<ItemFormat> Items = new List<ItemFormat>();
    DispatcherTimer PopulateIsoFile = new DispatcherTimer();
    string SongBuffer;
    int c = 1;
    string Time;

    #endregion

    #region AppInit
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No internet connection", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        }
        else
        {
            if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing)
            {
                PauseBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                PlayBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://air-online2.hitfm.md/hitfm.mp3"), "HITFM", "Включи себя", null, null);
                PlayBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                PauseBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged += Instance_PlayStateChanged;
            SlideView.Begin();
            SlideView.Completed += SlideView_Completed;
            SlideView.AutoReverse = true;
        }
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
        Loaded += timer_Tick;
    }
```

#region DownloadTrackInfo

```
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://air-online2.hitfm.md/status_hitfm.xsl"));
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException)
        {
        }
    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] raw = e.Result.Substring(166).Split('-');
            if (raw[0].Contains(":"))
            {
                Artist.Text = raw[0].Replace(":", string.Empty).Substring(0, raw[0].Length - 1);
                Title.Text = raw[1].Substring(1);
            }
            else
            {
                Artist.Text = raw[0];
                Title.Text = raw[1].Substring(1);
            }
            TitleProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Title.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            Artist.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            if (DateTime.Now.Minute < 10)
            {
                Time = "0" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Time = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            }
            ItemFormat Item = new ItemFormat(e.Result.Substring(166).Replace(":", string.Empty), c, DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + ":" + Time);
            if ((!(Item.Song == SongBuffer)) || (Recent.Items.Count == 0))
            {
                Recent.Items.Add(Item);
                SongBuffer = Item.Song;
                c += 1;
            }
        }
        catch (System.SystemException)
        {

        }
    }
```

}

```
public class ItemFormat
{
    public string Song { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public ItemFormat(string Song, int count, string time)
    {
        this.Song = Song;
        this.Count = count;
        this.Time = time;
    }
 }
```

}

I use this list box for a sort of a playlist for a radio. But i need my  items to be saved even when the user clicks back button or is under lock screen. Please help me save my dear items.

Comment: These items that are used to fill the `ListBox` in the first place, where do they come from?

Comment: I've updated with code.

Comment: I don't need to see all the code, that is too much for me to read tonight, as is for everybody else. Just paste the relevant part - where do you get your data from.

Comment: Thanks, much better now. So you use the `Items` property to fill the list? And you want to save that state for later use?

Comment: Yes i use the Items Class which is a ItemFormat class that has the properties written at the bottom. All i want is to save the listbox items which were populated by these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to store data between "sessions":

- Using files in the `IsolatedStorage` to serialize to/deserialize from.
- Using `IsolatedStorageSettings` for the same purpose, but with smaller amount of data.
- Using database, either SQL CE or sqlite

I suggest that you use the first method because it is the easiest one and you will get the least errors with it. Simply serialize the data to the file whenever you need to, either on application closing or when it changes. You then load the data on startup from the file (if it exists) and fill the initial list.

Comment: Can you show some examples ? because i tried the first method but with no success. I have deleted the codes:(